# Combline labels react-chartsjs-2

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs

i'm trying to combine labels in my x-axes:
[image]

now I have this result, but I want to have like this: [image]

this is my data:

```
const dataTest = {
  labels: [] as any,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Main Chart",
      fill: true,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
      borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
      borderCapStyle: "butt",
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      borderJoinStyle: "miter",
      pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
      pointBorderWidth: 1,
      pointHoverRadius: 5,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
      pointRadius: 1,
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      data: [] as any
    }
  ]
};
```

Thanks in forward!!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, i've found answer:
I needed to add:

```
xAxes: [
      {
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'month'
        }
      }
    ],
```

to an option object))